# Getting element width inside directive the Angular way

Tags: javascript, css, angularjs

I have a directive which contains an element inside it with `width: 100%`. However, the directive must know the `clientWidth` of that element -- that is, in pixels rather than percent. The element is buried deep in the directive's DOM.

The containing controller may have multiple instances of this directive, so doing `document.getElementsByClassName('myclass')[0].clientWidth` won't work. Selecting the directive's `element` works, but the code for that looks similar to `element.children().children().children()[32].clientWidth`, which doesn't look very stable. What is the right, Angular way of doing this?

Comment: Why does it need to know the width?

Comment: The controller should not have to know the directive's width. That level of view logic doesn't belong in a Controller. So, basically, the Angular way is to avoid placing any of that logic in the controller. Maybe you want a wrapper directive to handle your view logic. The directive, however, can say `element[0].clientWidth` to get its own width.

Comment: You're both right, I realized I didn't need it in the containing controller. I will edit the question appropriately. Still, I need to get the width of the element just for the directive. This results in code like `element.children().children().children()[32].clientWidth`. Is there anything cleaner?

Comment: The parent directive encompasses a number of things. I suppose another way to have done this could've been to create a directive specifically for the element I care about, then pass it up to the parent directive via an attribute.

Comment: One reason you might need to do this is for `canvas`/`svg`, which do not really follow the standard box model. You have to set the width & height as attributes, but how do you get them to set them before the page loads?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Whenever you need to do any DOM manipulation in Angular, directives are the way to go. The "Angular" approach would be to use your [directive's link](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive#creating-a-directive-that-manipulates-the-dom) function.

DEMO: http://plnkr.co/edit/83aZUmsRzuTUFotxUYSB?p=preview

Template Use Case:

```
<div element-width></div>
```

Directive Example:

```
angular.module('myApp').directive('elementWidth',function(){
    return {
        restrict: "A",
        link:function($scope, element){
          // element param being passed in refers 
          // to the element the directive is bound to, in this case, the DIV


          // do something with the element width here
        }
    }
});
```

Hope this helps and let me know if you have any questions.

Comment: Thanks! I like it a lot more than my answer.

Answer (score -1):

I figured it out. Although single elements do not have `.getElementsByClassName`, you can still use `.querySelector`. So my finished code was:

`element[0].querySelector('.myclass').clientWidth`